# logistic differential equation, carrying capacity.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that a population grows according to the below logistic differential equation $$\frac{\mathrm{dP} }{\mathrm{d} t}=0.01P-0.0002P^2$$
Then what is the maximum population that this model holds?

I think the answer is 50000(I can be wrong!!). Can anyone show me the steps of how to do this? using direction fields? or solve the differential equation directly? and then how do you get the maximum population? Thank you.

Comment: Would you like to show us how you get $5000$? It will be easier for us to check your steps and provide suggestions then.

Comment: Hi, I used the direction field(Plotted in a software) , and something happens in 50000, so I think the answer is 50000, but I am very uncertain to this answer.

Comment: Sorry it is 50000, not 5000.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is to set dP/dt =0 and solve the quadratic for P. It is not rigorous, but it gets the answer provided one exists.

Comment: @Deepak It gets the long run population. It does not provide a max/min. It also says nothing about whether the population is monotone increasing/decreasing (it may oscillate wildly before hand). But yes, if you only want long term pop, then that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is separable. It is also a [Ricatti equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) (thus linearisable) if you are interested. We have
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = aP(1-bP) \implies \int\frac{dP}{P(1-bP)} = \int a\,dt$$
where $a=\frac{1}{100}$ and $b=\frac{1}{50}$. By partial fractions
$$\frac{1}{P(1-bP)} = \frac{1}{P} + \frac{b}{1-bP}$$
and substituting into the integral
$$\ln|P|-\ln|1-bP| = at+c \implies \frac{P}{1-bP} = Ce^{at}$$
where $c$ is a constant of integration and $C=\pm e^c$. Rearranging we get
$$P=\frac{Ce^{at}}{1+bCe^{at}} = \frac{Ce^{\frac{1}{100}t}}{1+\frac{1}{50}Ce^{\frac{1}{100}t}} = 50\frac{Ce^{\frac{1}{100}t}}{50+Ce^{\frac{1}{100}t}} = \frac{50}{Ae^{-\frac{1}{100}t}+1}$$
for some arbitrary $A=\frac{50}{C}$. Thus the long run population is $P\to 50$.

Note also that $P\equiv 0$ is a solution to the equation. Assuming that $0<P_0<50$, then the solution monotone increases from $P_0$ to $50$.

Comment: yes!! Thank you so much! then why is 50000, not 50?

Comment: What do you mean? Where does $50000$ come from?

Comment: Never mind, it's just my given solution is 50000, that's weird...

Comment: But there is no maximum anyway. If $P_0>50$ then the population decreases to $50$, and $50$ is the minimum.

Comment: As for the $50000$, I do not know... I cannot see a mistake.

Comment: Also, minimum/maximum is poor terminology. Really, unless $P_0=50$ then they are infimum/supremum.

Comment: oh, I got it, I just saw something in my question. Your solution is 100% right, thank you!